# Javascript date + milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am working on a pause function for a timer I have built and I am getting a little stuck.

As soon as the timer starts, I capture the current date in milliseconds:

```
if(!begin){
   begin = Date.now();
}
```

Once the user has clicked pause, it will then get the current date in milliseconds.

```
// Pause the timer
function pause(){
   console.log('Begin : ' + begin) //Begin : 1467580324524
   console.log('End: ' + currentDate().getTime()) //End: 1467580329936
   console.log('Difference: ' + parseInt(begin - currentDate().getTime())) //Difference: -5414
   clearInterval(interval);
}
```

I now have a variable called `difference` that contains the number of milliseconds between the start time and stop time.

When the user clicks "Resume", I need to get the current date and add the difference of milliseconds we got. That should then resume the timer from where they currently left off using the new point in time.

How can I go about adding the milliseconds to the current date in order to get the new starting point?

I tried something like this with no luck:

```
var mili = 4512;
var newDate = new Date(mili*1000);
```

UPDATE: here is a link to my timer code so you can see what I am working with.
https://jsfiddle.net/3dweffy8/3/

I got the timer to pause by clearing the interval but I am not sure how to continue with getting the timer to resume at this point.

Comment: this is not best algorithm, why would you consume cpu while user is pausing when you can just increment your timer from where you paused ?

Comment: Can you provide, what you expect in the end after start->pause->resume->pause->resume? Do you expect the time of the transitions as a sum or do you expect a list of times, each giving the time to transition between the nth and (n+1)nth state.

Comment: @thst - I actually just ran into that issue. Start > Pause > Resume works fine but when I pause and resume it again, it jumps as if it never stopped counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current timestamp using `Date.now()`, add the amount of milliseconds and make a new `Date` object from it:

```
var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + mili)
```

Comment: Why not simply use `Date.now()`? Much more efficient then instantiating an instance every time (2 instances even!).

Answer (score 0):

Write an Object to do the bookkeeping.

The object will carry the last timestamp and the measurements, either as a sum or as an array.

It exposes function `start()`, `stop()`, `pause()`, `resume()`.

in `start()`: reset the measurements and get the current Date as `referenceDate` for your next measurement. If the tracker is already running, do nothing.

`stop()`: calculate the difference between current date and `referenceDate`. The counter is no longer active. Maybe archive the remaining results.

`pause()`: calculate the difference between current date and `referenceDate`. If you want to measure breaks, set `referenceDate` to current date.

`resume()`: If you measure breaks, calculate the difference between current date and `referenceDate`. 
In any case, set `referenceDate` to current date.

Usage:

```
var tracker = new Tracker();

// start 
tracker.start(); 

// Pause the timer
function pause(){
   tracker.pause();

   console.log('Begin : ' + tracker.startOfEvents); //Begin:1467580324524
   console.log('End: ' + tracker.lastMeasurement); //End: 1467580329936
   console.log('Difference: ' + tracker.difference) //Difference: -5414

   // was this part of your measurement?
   clearInterval(interval);
}

// later
tracker.resume();
```